# In MongoMapper, how to use before filter to set required field?

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

Every Person should have the initials field set, but it is set upon create.

```
class Person
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :first_name, String, required:true
  key :last_name,  String, required:true
  key :initials,   String, required:true
  timestamps!

  before_create :create_initials

  def create_initials
    @initals = @first_name[0] + @last_name[0]
  end
end

Person.create!( first_name: 'Joe', last_name: 'Brown' )
```

Apparently this fails because the model is validated before the before filter is called.

Checking [AR Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) shows this is the case. However, this also fails with the `before_save` filter.

What is a good way to set a required field upon creation in MongoMapper?

Answer (score 1):

Try using after_initialize

```
class Person
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :first_name, String, required:true
  key :last_name,  String, required:true
  key :initials,   String, required:true
  timestamps!

  after_initialize :create_initials

  def create_initials
    @initals = @first_name[0] + @last_name[0]
  end
end
```

Comment: Reference - [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: Works for AR, but not MongoMapper: https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper/issues/59

Comment: @BSeven Did you try before_validation ?